# A high variability in A is associated with outcome X : The use of the Coefficient of Variation to predict outcomes?

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation, variability

I want to know whether the Coefficient of Variation is a valid tool for the following problem:

The goal is to assess whether high variability in blood concentrations of a pharmaceutical drug is associated with a particular outcome, f.e. early death.

Let us assume I have 100 patients. For each patient I have >5 observations, each representing a blood sample taken on a different day. Also, I know whether event X occured during the study period.

Now, I can calulate the mean and the standard deviation of drug concentrations for each patient.

Option A: Assess whether low/high mean or high standard deviation is associated with outcome X.

Option B: Calculate the coefficient of variation for each patient and see whether a high coefficient of variation is associated with outcome X.

I believe B is flawed.

Firstly: IF there is a relationship between high variation and blood levels and outcome X, then the standard deviation should be enough.

Secondly: Mean levels confound the results when variation is assessed based on CV, and not on SD. F.e. a patient with a high mean value but average SD would be classified as having "below average variation"

In summary, I do not understand why the Coefficent of variation might be a valid tool to assess variability in blood levels of the same drug.

Furthermore, would the CV even be useful to compare the variablity of two different drugs if they have the same target concentration? Again, I believe mean values would confound even if they had the same target values - and if we assume mean values to be equal, then we might as well use the standard deviation in the first place.

Thank you so much!